# Typescript and hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Could anyone advise me on the best way to convert this hook to a type safe version using Typescript please. Its a simple toggle to display a different 'thing' on toggle state.

useToggle.js

```
const useToggleButton = ({on,off}) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false)

  const ToggleButton = () => (
    <div
      role="button"
      onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
      data-testid="portal-toggle-btn"
    >
      {toggle? on : off}
    </div>
  )
  return [ToggleButton, toggle, setToggle]
}
```

The thing is that it returns an array with the component, state and setState function.  My attempt is below but I get the errors

```
TS2605: JSX element type 'IReturnType' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.   Type 'IReturnType' is missing the
following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key

TS2739: Type '(boolean | Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>)[]' is
missing the following properties from type 'IReturnType': component,
state, func
```

useToggle.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface IToggleBntProps {
  on: any
  off: any
}

interface IState {
  bol: boolean
}

interface IReturnType {
  component: React.FunctionComponent
  state: boolean
  func: (bol: boolean) => IState
}

const useToggleButton = ({ on, off }: IToggleBntProps): IReturnType => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false)

  const ToggleButton = () => (
    <div
      role="button"
      onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
      data-testid="portal-toggle-btn"
    >
      {toggle ? on : off}
    </div>
  )
  return [ToggleButton, toggle, setToggle]
}

export default useToggleButton
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript can actually figure out most of these types automatically!

In the code below, saying `as const` ([a const assertion](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#const-assertions)) at the end of your return statement lets TypeScript correctly infer the return type you want: `[() => JSX.Element, boolean, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>]`.

If you wanted to be explicit, you could do `type IReturnType = [() => JSX.Element, boolean, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>]`, but that's verbose and unnecessary.

```
interface IToggleBntProps {
  on: any
  off: any
}

const useToggleButton = ({ on, off }: IToggleBntProps) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false)

  const ToggleButton = () => (
    <div
      role="button"
      onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
      data-testid="portal-toggle-btn"
    >
      {toggle ? on : off}
    </div>
  )

  // saying 'as const' here means that TypeScript automatically
  // knows that this should be a tuple type of three elements.
  // Not you need TypeScript 3.4 or newer 
  return [ToggleButton, toggle, setToggle] as const;
}

export default useToggleButton
```

Comment: JKillian you legend. Thanks